# dojo drag n drop (DND) not working

Tags: tree, drag-and-drop, dojo

I have dojo tree and a list of items that can be added to the tree.  Would like to use dojo dnd (drag n drop) so that items in the list can be dragged onto the tree to add them.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/goinoff/mk67ddr0/)

When you mouse-down on a unassigned list item and drag it onto the tree, nothing appears to happen, but if you look at the web browser console, you can see that it always complains about `TypeError: a is undefined` in dojo's `Memory.js` module.

I am trying to do something similar to this example [Dojo drag-n-drop example](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.1/dojo-release-1.10.1/dijit/tests/tree/test_Tree_DnD.html).  In this example, grab an item from the `items` list and drag it onto the tree on the right (Collection tree).

I am using dojo 1.10.4 and also new to using trees and drag-n-drop (dojo dnd).  What am I missing here to be able to drag-n-drop from the list onto the tree??

Answer (score 0):

I used Dojo Tree on the left of the screen and [Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) (https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) for the list on the right. It is very simple and it works.

Here there is the list object example with Dragula.

```
this.dnd = dragula([this.list], {
       isContainer: function (el) {
         return el.classList.contains('dijitTreeRow');
       }
     });
     this.dnd.on('shadow', function (el, container, source) {         // the event when yoi drag something tipo hover
     //   console.log(el, container);
       var oldContainer;                                         // change color of the drop item
       oldContainer = query('.dndHover')[0];
       if (oldContainer) {                                       
         domClass.remove(oldContainer, 'dndHover');
       }
       if (container === source) {                               // if drag and drop on the list do nothing
         return;
       }
       domClass.add(container, 'dndHover');                  // highlight current node
     });



     this.dnd.on('drop', function (el, container, source) {           // drop event
        var oldContainer;                                         // remove highlight
        oldContainer = query('.dndHover')[0];
        if (oldContainer) {
           domClass.remove(oldContainer, 'dndHover');
        }
        if (container !== source) {
           // var widget = registry.getEnclosingWidget(el);
           var target = registry.getEnclosingWidget(container);
           // console.log(el, target);

           // target = TREE NODE
           // make your action (query, etc..)

        }
     }.bind(this));
```

CSS:

```
.dndHover{
   background-color: #52D017 !important;
}

.dijitTreeRow .dragdiv {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try Stefano..Thx!!